# Export large lotus database

Tags: export, lotus-domino, lotus

What is the best way to export data from [lotus](/questions/tagged/lotus) database containing more than 100k documents with a lot of fields? Application logic is not required, just the data stored within the application. The database does not contain form design element for every document. LEI is not an option for us.

1. Currently we use java agent to export data to MS EXCEL, but the
   running time is too long.
2. [notes-sql](/questions/tagged/notes-sql) could be faster,
3. ...  or is there any alternate solution which can be fast enough?

Comment: You need only free solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the quickest way that gets everything is to export to DXL, then read that DXL for the data you want.

Here is some sample code to export the first selected documented in a database (LotusScript agent). Writes a file called C:\temp\data.xml.

```
Option Public
Option Declare

Sub Initialize
    Dim nsn As New NotesSession
    Dim ndb As NotesDatabase
    Dim ndc As NotesDocumentCollection
    Dim ndo As NotesDocument
    Dim ndxle As NotesDXLExporter
    Dim nst As NotesStream
    On Error Resume Next

    Set ndb = nsn.CurrentDatabase
    Set ndc = ndb.UnprocessedDocuments
    Set ndo = ndc.GetFirstDocument

    Set nst = nsn.createStream
    If (Not(nst.Open( "c:\temp\DATA.xml" ))) Then
        Print "Open File DATA.xml Failed" 
    End If
    nst.truncate

    Set ndxle = nsn.CreateDXLExporter (ndo, nst)

    ndxle.Convertnotesbitmapstogif = true ' Not always needed.

    Call ndxle.Process()
    MsgBox ndxle.Log
    Call nst.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

An efficient and easy way to get the data as XML to a file would be retrieving it with URLs like this:

```
/view?ReadViewEntries&Start=1&Count=1000
```

You would have a code fetching all 100K in chunks of 1000 (this value may be adjusted depending on amount of data but if it's too big the server might hang).

The view contains all documents and all items as columns.

This approach puts a lot of load to server HTTP task so it might be best to run it at a quiet time.

If you need to get the data to Excel then you have to take a look at the current agent and see if it could be optimized.